Are Windows Service dependencies taken into account when resuming from sleep?
On Windows you can control services' dependencies start order by setting DependOnService and DependOnGroup.
Does Windows also guarantee the dependencies order when resuming from sleep or should I explicitly check the other service status, and wait if necessary?
Our service uses PowerRegisterResumeNotification() and when handling PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC I can see that the other service is running, but I want to be certain that it will be indeed the case in all circumstances.

For fun, I also asked the question to ChatGPT and got an answer stating that the order is not enforced when resuming from sleep. As I could find not any doc that says that the order are enforced or contradicts the above, this might actually be the correct answer.

Windows only checks dependencies on initial service start. It doesn't restart services when resuming from sleep, so it won't check dependencies. Only if it goes into Stopped state first

In sleep mode (standby if suspend tk ram) no processes or services are stopped - only the CPU or better the execution of code from those processes itself is stopped.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
